# VBA Workbook Address

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro, workbook `MACRO`, that has to open another workbook, lets call it `OPEN`.

The problem is the workbooks `OPEN` and `MACRO` are on the net and the `OPEN`'s address is up to the person who runs the macro.

I mean, if I run the macro the address is:

```
X:\Destkop\OPEN.xlsm
```

but, for example, if the macro is run by another person, the address could change:

```
Y:\Destkop\OPEn.xlsm
```

so for the macro it is imposible to open the workbook `OPEN` and it doesn't run the code.

To get the address I use the following code:

```
activeworkbook.fullname
```

but the problem is that code will return the address of the `OPEN` in my computer not on the "net".

Is there anyway to know/get the address of any workbook placed on the net???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the mapped drive letter, use the UNC address. `X:\` and `Y:\` are most likely different aliases (for want of a better term) to the same place which can also be expressed in UNC form as

```
\\ServerName\SharedFolder\
```

So the full path would be `\\ServerName\SharedFolder\Desktop\Open.xlsm`

You should be able to use that in the command to open the workbook and it will no longer matter which drive letter they have the share mapped to or indeed whether they have it mapped at all, as long as they have access to it.

Comment: Incidentally, if you don't know the UNC path go to a command line window (just type cmd in the search programs and files box on the Start menu to open one) on one of the computers and type net use then [Enter] to see the network shares, amongst other things.